# Excel VBA - If two variables are present, cell = this particular value (Not "=IF(AND(" function)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Currently I have a database that has 2 variables:

1. Fund with an ID attached to it and
2. Investor with an ID also attached to it.

The example attached, has 4 funds and 4 investors.

An investor can invest in 1 to 4 funds.

I have a VBA function that transposes the data into an "X & Y axis" format.

If there is a name "Ben & Jerry Fund" and "Ben" is present, it should show a quarter entry for that investor name but if the investor does not invest in the fund, it should just be blank.

**Question:** Is this possible?

Using the `=IF(AND(` function would not be possible here since there's so many funds and investors in the database.

Figure 1 shows the data reference (before transposing).

Figure 2 is the desired result.

[image: Figure 1 and 2]

Comment: Appreciate the edit @jwpfox , much clearer than my initial explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=IFERROR(INDEX($E$3:$E$12,SMALL(IF($C$3:$C$12=L$5,IF($A$3:$A$12=$K7,ROW($A$3:$A$12)-ROW($A$2))),1)),"")`

Building an array of row numbers for INDEX and grabbing the first match (smallest row) based on the 2 if statements...

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply. Took me some time to play with the configurations but your seems to work the best. Really appreciate the help mate, cheers!! :)

Comment: @Ben No problem, always happy to help

Comment: just wondering, is it possible to make the cell's range dynamic?

Comment: @Ben It is possible using something like `INDIRECT()` or `OFFSET()` but these are volatile formulas (they recalculate every time any change is made in the spreadsheet) so they can really affect performance... There may be other methods but not off the top of my head... I usually move to VBA when I start to make dynamic formula.

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose is to have a dynamic report. I mean if you want to append more years and avoid operative process. Follow this steeps:

1. Use "Format as table" for your data. This will allow you to append more data later and it will refresh the functions by itself.
2. Create a field to extract just the quarter number in the field [Quarter] with `=MID([Quarter],1,1)`
3. Create a field to extract the year `=RIGHT([Quarter],4)` this will allow you to use this field as a filter for future years
4. Create a pivot table using the new table then organize the data:

   *Filter([Year])

   *Rows([Fund Name], [Fund Id])

   *Columns([Inversor], [Inversor ID])

   *Values ([Quarter])
5. You will see the numbers for the quarter. If you want to see the letter "Q" you can change the format with right click, and select "Number Format...". There in "Custom" change to `Q0`

Here is a [Tutorial](https://youtu.be/RQFekY7RXEk) about format as table and pivot tables that I made a few months ago. I am sorry it is in Spanish but I am using the Excel English version.

Comment: I'm currently using Excel 2007. Column number is about 100, but row numbers can reach numbers from a 1000 onwards.

Comment: Please use the comments section to ask for more information, answers is for solutions only

Comment: Ben I updated my answer I hope that it gives you an idea for your report. @Richard Tompsett I am sorry as I said I am new here and I don't have enough points to comment yet.

Comment: No problem, down-vote removed now that the post constitutes an answer... Good luck nabbing the rep

Comment: Hey there @virtualvid , thanks for the feedback but it seems that when I used the pivot table, some problems would occur. Maybe I'm just not skilled enough at this point of time, but really appreciate the help once again!! I used Richard Tompsett's solution instead :)

Answer (score -1):

A pivot table can achieve what you want?

Comment: Consider posting an example of what you are proposing.

Comment: Can't use a Pivot Table because it doesn't show the raw value (e.g. Q1 2017)

Comment: Create a new "Quarter" field:
 - add a new column with the heading "Qtr". In this column, type a 1 for "Q1 2017" and 2 for Q2 2017. 
 - Do a pivot table.
 - Right-click on one of the numbers in the Values Area
- In the popup menu, click summarize by Max                                   
Apply a Custom Number Format:
- Right-click a Region value in the Values area in the pivot table.
- In the popup menu, click Number Format.
- In the Category list, click Custom.
- In the Type box, enter [=1]"Q1 2017";[=2]“Q2 2017”;General